# using image as reset button

Tags: html, css, image, reset-button

i want to use an image as reset button what code i should use in HTML and CSS ?

Answer (score 7):

Think this should do the trick.

```
 <button type="reset">
    <img src="#" alt="" />
 </button>
```

Comment: It shouldn't change the shape of the image unless you specified a width/height on the image/button?

Answer (score 4):

Good question. Can't be done AFAIK. Images can only serve as submit buttons.
You would have to use Javascript to do a `onclick="this.form.reset()"` on a normal image, or style a normal reset button using a background image (should be possible without problems).

Comment: Check out MiGs approach, it works without JS and you just have to style the button. The Javascript I quote above you would just put into the image tag `<a href='...' onclick= .... `