# How do I stop this.form.reset() from firing my form action?

Tags: javascript, html

Okay here is my issue. I am using custom graphics for my submit/reset form buttons, but as soon as you press reset the form action is committed and I do not want that to happen and I have been searching the internet for a answer without any luck. I am including the form code as well in hopes as I might of just missed something.

```
<form class="contact" name="con_form" action="../includes/mailer.php">
            First Name*: <input type="text" name="first_name" value="" /><br />
            Last Name*: <input type="text name="last_name" value="" /><br />
            Contact Number*: (<input type="text" name="area_code" value="" size="3" />) <input type="text" name="first_three" value="" size="3" /> <input type="text" name="last_four" value="" size="4" /><br />
            Email Address*: <input type="text" name="email" value="" /><br />
            I would like to*: 
            <select>
                <option>--- Select One ---</option>
                <option>Comment</option>
                <option>Suggestion</option>
                <option>Inquiry for employment</option>
            </select><br />
            Comment or Suggestion: <textarea size="1024"></textarea><br /><br />
            <input type="image" src="images/sub_idle.gif" onsubmit="../index.php" alt="Submit" /> <input type="image" onclick="this.form.reset()" src="images/res_idle.gif" alt="Reset" />
        </form>
```

Comment: This should help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1994509/using-image-as-reset-button

Answer (score 1):

`input type="image"` defines the image as a submit button. If you just want it to be a clickable image that triggers some javascript, there's no need to make it an `input` at all.

Answer (score 1):

the `<input type="image"` input is actually a submit button

I would try this as a starting point: (not the best way probably)

```
<img onclick="this.form.reset();" src="images/res_idle.gif" alt="Reset" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use input `type=image`, use an `A`-tag with a CSS background.

```
<a href="#" class="buttonImage" onclick="document.con_form.reset();return false"></a>

.buttonImage {
    background-image:url(/images/sub_idle.gif);
    height:20px;
    width:60px;
    display:block
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the type to "button" and apply a css class to the button to customize the button.

```
<input type="button" onclick="this.form.reset()" class="resetbutton" />
```